# What means the statement "Select ... for all Entries ..."

Tags: select, abap, opensql

I was trying to do select for all entries in select statement - abap. I'm not getting the clear idea what select for entries does. Does any one know ?

Kindly have a look at the statements below:

1.

```
select bukrs belnr xblnr budat 
    from bkpf 
    into table it_bkpf 
    where belnr in s_belnr
```

2.

```
 select bukrs belnr buzei gsber zuonr wrbtr kunnr 
    from bseg 
    into table it_bseg  
    for all entries in it_bkpf 
    where belnr = it_bkpf-belnr.
```

Please let me know the difference in two statements.

Siva

Comment: 27 questions and only 2 accepted? Please work on that.

Comment: The difference appears to be that the statements have entirely different lists of columns, but as ther is no info on the table layout there is not a lot I can help with on this.  More time spent explaining the situation would help.

Comment: @damir: The column names are from standard SAP tables so unless you want to use aliases, there is no way around these names (which do have a bit of meaning in German ;-))

Answer (score 4):

Some obvious differences:

1. Different tables
2. Different target fields
3. The 2nd select had a syntax problem: You used `form` instead `from` (I corrected it with my edit)

Other differences:

The selection 1.) uses `in` in the `where` clause. So it uses a `select-options` (or a `range`-object).

`for all entries in it_bkpf` means, that the internal table `it_bkpf` contains a list of elements, you want to select. Or in other words: Select all entries in bseg, where a filed belnr is an element of hte internal table bseg.

Answer (score 3):

You will get clear answer through **ST05** transaction.

- You could execute st05 transaction, choose trace SQL and activate
  trace.
- After that run your code.
- Enter st05 again choose deactivate trace, then view trace result.

There you can see exact SQL code that is forwarded to database server. As BSEG is clustered table, you could not use intuitive header-item join to retrieve needed financial movements inforamation. It's just because there are several tables including BSEG are storing in single database table, so database server technically can not separate BSEG rows and find BSEG-specific fields to make proper join.

So you can do join-like construction at application server. First you are retrieving all header-related columns from header table ( BKPF). Next when `SELECT ... FOR ALL ENTRIES IN ...` is executed application server will take a little portions of header rows (typically 5) and construct SQL queries for retrieving packs of items, corresponding to that portions. Next all that portions will merged in single internal table. So there will be only items of desired document as it were if you could execute normal join.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what happens the way I understand it. The two statements are probably executed after another:

1. The first statement selects a few entries from the bkpf table. These entries are stored in the internal table it_bkpf (say belnr 1, 2, 3).
2. Each of these entries is then used as part of the select #2. The "for all entries" matches the belnr in table bseg to those in the internal table it_bkpf from the first statement. The matching entries are then put into the internal table it_bseg.

With the example you've given this is pretty much the same if the where clause in SQL #2 was `where belnr in s_belnr` (instead of the whole for all entries). This would only make sense if you needed the contents of it_bkpf for some other purpose. Another typical situation is if you determine the contents of the internal table used in the for all entries clause with some program logic instead of reading it directly from the database.

One catch with "for all entries": Make sure the internal table in the `for all entries` is not empty - then the whole table in the from clause would be selected.